# saving extracted text from images into file in raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-tesseract, espeak

code for extracting text from images and calling for espeak
[image: code for extracting text from images and calling for espeak]

Error
[image: error]

getting same error while redirecting it into a file instead of printing 
and print function is printing it properly

Comment: images are in above link

Comment: Please post your code and error as formatted part of your question and not as images. Judging from the error you're getting. it is a character encoding issue. You can take a look at [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: show your code as text